# Should the Interop Structure Memory be Freed After Calling?

Tags: .net, c++, interop

I have the following function and structures in C++ code that are designed for interop:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) typedef struct
{
    int num_vertices;
    int *vertices;

} Vertex_List;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) typedef struct
{
    int num_cycles;
    Vertex_List *cycles;
} Cycle_List;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) typedef struct
{
    int v1;
    int v2;

} Edge;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) typedef struct
{
    int num_edges;
    Edge *edgeList;
} Edge_List;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Cycle_List Traversal(Edge_List edgeList);
```

And This is my corresponding .Net structure code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct EdgeSpecial
{
    public int v1;
    public int v2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Edge_List                 
{
    public int num_edges; 
    public IntPtr edgeList;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal  struct  Vertex_List
{
    public int num_vertices;
    public IntPtr vertices;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal  struct Cycle_List
{
    public int num_cycles;
    public IntPtr cycles;
}

[DllImport("BoostAPI.dll")]
public static extern Cycle_List Traversal([In] Edge_List edgeList);
```

This is how I do my call in .Net function:

```
//converts from my edge structure to the interop structure
Edge_List edgeList = EdgeConvertor(edges); 

//interop call
Cycle_List cycleInterop = GraphBoostInterop.Traversal(edgeList);              

// converts from interop cycle structure to my .NET structure
var cycleList = CycleListConvertor(cycleInterop);
```

The issue is, after the `cycleInterop` is converted to my data structure `cycleList`, is there any need to free `edgeList` and `cycleInterop`? Should I create `FreeCycle` or such code inside C++ and then pass the structure into it for freeing the memory purpose? If yes, how?

Edit: This is how the Cycle_List is populated in C++; basically I just copy the information from a similar data structure ( using `std::vector` to it).

```
  i=0;
    Cycle_List cList;
    cList.num_cycles=cycleList.CycleList.size();
        cList.cycles=(Vertex_List*)malloc(cList.num_cycles*sizeof(Vertex_List));
    for(std::vector<Cycle>::const_iterator it = cycleList.CycleList.begin(); it !=  cycleList.CycleList.end(); ++it)
  {


      Cycle cycle = *it;
      Vertex_List vList;
      vList.num_vertices = cycle.VertexList.size();
          vList.vertices= (int*) malloc ( vList.num_vertices*sizeof(int));
      j=0;
      for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator intList=cycle.VertexList.begin(); intList!=cycle.VertexList.end(); ++intList)
      {
          vList.vertices[j++] = *intList;    

      }

      cList.cycles[i++]=vList;



  }
```

Comment: [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) is an excellent graph library written in C#. Its API was designed to closely match Boost.

Comment: @Tim, as good as it is, some of the algorithms are simply not available in QuickGraph.

Comment: Fair enough. In answer to your question: `Cycle_List` contains an `IntPtr`, so you'll have to free something. But the right function will be somewhere inside Boost; you should read the Boost documentation.

Comment: @Tim, what do you mean? `Cycle_List` is my *own* data structure wrapped around Boost.

Comment: Where did `Cycle_List.cycles` come from? Whichever C++ function you're using to allocate it, you'll need to call the matching C++ function to deallocate it.

Comment: @Tim, as shown in the second structure definition, it is something that I define

Comment: Can you show the C++ code that populates a `Cycle_List` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsibility of the releasing is by whoever has allocated the memory. As simple as it seem, this is the golden rule.

According to this rule, when an unmanaged DLL returns me a pointer to an unmanaged structure it means that **it** has allocated the memory. So releasing the memory would require calling the unmanaged DLL to release it when you are done - which seems to be at the time you finish converting the unmanaged pointer to managed structure.

I am not familiar with your unmanaged library but I have used OpenCV and it has `cvRelease(**ptr)` which releases the memory and resets the pointer back to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're populating the `Cycle_List` structure inside your own C++ code, you should write a second C++ function that frees a `Cycle_List` structure.

Since you're using `malloc` to initialize the `Cycle_List::cycles` and `Vertex_List::vertices` members, you should use `free` to clean them up.

As @Aliostad says, "responsibility of the releasing is by whoever has allocated the memory".